# Why does jquery_3.4 cause multiple clicks

Tags: jquery

The application is written for a browser but intended to run on a phone. The checkbox controls look like sliders. Clicking on the slider or the surrounding row results in a command being sent to another device. The response (not shown) causes the display to be updated. It works fine when using jquery_3.3.1 but continuous clicks are generated when using jquery_3.4.0 or jquery_3.6.0.

The html for one control.

```
<li>
    <button id="main_zone_mute" class="nav-toggle-item">
        <span>Mute</span>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="switch_track round" tabindex="0"></span>
        </label>
    </button>
</li>
```

The JavaScript for one control.

```
$("#main_zone_mute").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("main_zone_mute clicked " + e.target.nodeName + " " + (parseInt(e.timeStamp) % 1000));
    $("#main_zone_mute input[type=checkbox]").click();
});
$("#main_zone_mute input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(e){
    var value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    console.log("main_zone_mute checkbox changed " + value);
    send_and_query_command(get_zone_command(COMMAND.Z_MUT, zone_number), value);
});
```

With jquery 3.3.3, clicking on the slider causes a `click` event from SPAN and INPUT and clicking on the rest of the row causes a `click` event from BUTTON and INPUT. Only one `changed` event is reported.

With jquery 3.4, the same first event results followed by `click` events from INPUT until the stack overflows. What is different between the versions that could cause so many `click` events to be generated? What can I do to avoid the issue?

I have tried placing `.off("click")` before `.on(..)`, `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `e.stopPropagation()` and disabling the `"#main_zone_mute"` control. None of these methods fixed the problem.

I tried addEventListener("click", ..), which did work but I would prefer to keep the language consistent.

Comment: Seems like you're making things more difficult than need be here. Looks like your button essentially acts as a 'label' - why not stylize a label?

Comment: I will think about it. All of the other controls cause the loading of a new page.

Comment: I have added sample code. It works with jquery 3.3.1 and fails with jquery 3.4.0. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/JoeAB/3jvb5a47/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I did not determine the cause of the problem so I modified the code (x30).

```
$("#main_zone_mute").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var bwas = $("#main_zone_mute input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked");
    send_and_query_command(get_zone_command(COMMAND.Z_MUT, zone_number), bwas ? 0 : 1); // toggle
});
```